# Displaying multiple level grouping dataview on a web part

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part, custom, grouping

Is there a way to display a dataview control with multiple level grouping on a custom web part, not using SPD.

Right now, I'm using SPGridView control but It does not support multiple level grouping.
I'm querying the data from several lists.

I want something like this, or even more than 2 levels:

```
- Business Area I
  - Area A
     Item 1
     Item 2   
  + Area B   
  + Area C
+ Business Area II
```

But I'm afraid I have to use JQuery plugin or something else...

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Why not use a [TreeView control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140827/Dynamic-Binding-Of-Hierarchy-Data-Structure-To-Tre)

Comment: That solves the multilevel grouping, but I want it to display as a dataview with multiple columns, like when you work on a single list and display the data with OOTB views.

Comment: Create a tabular format view then use jQuery datatable with grouping plugin. See example here: https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/twoLevelGrouping.html

Answer (score 1):

`SharePoint:ListViewByQuery` might do the trick.

I found this example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/906a43a4-2724-45de-b1ab-285f64229e83/multi-level-grouping-in-spgridview-programmatically

```
<SharePoint:ListViewByQuery ID="CustomersListViewByQuery" runat="server" Width="700px" />
```

In Code behind

```
SPList oList = web.GetList("CustomTask");

CustomersListViewByQuery.List = oList;

SPQuery query = new SPQuery(oList.DefaultView);

query.Query= "<GroupBy Collapse='FALSE'><FieldRef Name='Department' /><FieldRef Name='Status' /></GroupBy>";

CustomersListViewByQuery.Query = query;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but this method works when you use only one list, but I'm getting my data from several lists (as I mentioned on the question)...

Comment: My apologies. I missed that. Let me keep looking...